# What caused this red spot on my Haworthia plant?

Tags: diagnosis, succulents

My [Haworthia](http://succulent-plant.com/families/aloaceae/haworthia.html) plant has this strange red spot. I'm not sure what it is - is my plant okay?

[image]

Comment: Looks remarkably like a burn of some sort and it doesn't look red in the pic.. not sure what it is, but it looks healthy otherwise

Comment: It DOES look like a burn...a cigarette burn?  I can't think of a single disease where there is only one spot on a very healthy plant.  Liz, do you allow smoking friends to smoke in your home?  I'd get a magnifying glass and the tip of a razor blade to look up close.  If it is a burn it will look like charcoal in that magnifying glass.  Speaking of magnifying glass, do you have precocious   kids around?

Comment: @stormy Nah, no cigarettes, no kids and no smoking friends... I mean, I could have bought my Haworthia plant like this but I honestly can't remember seeing this spot before. By the way, could it be caused by an insect/spider? And yeah, it looks totally red in real life. I can also take a macro photo if you think it might help.

Comment: @Liz A close-up photo will definitely help. But it does look like a burn. Don't know about insects, but if there are spiders, you are more likely to see webs. Right?

Comment: if not a burn it could be a mealy bug

Answer (score 1):

Haworthia, Gasteria & Aloe are all closely related.  They can all get black spot, which can look red or brown.  As a general rule they have good defences systems that protect them from disease.  It is not uncommon for them to get one or two black spot and none anywhere else.   They rarely have to be treated with any kind of spray.  They will grow out of it.  If it continues, before you spray improve the air flow around the plant.  Make sure it is not jammed up against another plant.  Also improve the amount of light it gets.  Often making these two changes will stop the black spot.   That should be all you need to do for this particular species.  If it were a Gasteria it might still require a systemic fungicide spray done twice, two weeks apart.  I doubt this plant got many if any more spots.